# HQL query to retrieve only one parent column using nested child record

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am using oracle db and hibernate 4 for my development. I have following tables

```
Table => Shops
columns :
 id(Pk),
 name

Table => Authors
columns :
 id(Pk),
 name,
 shopId(FK from Shop)

Table => Books
columns :
 id(Pk),
 name,
 authorId(FK from Author)
```

Now Books are connected to Author with "Many to One" relationship and similarly Author connected to Shop with "Many to One". These relationships are eagerly loaded.
Now i would like to just get shop name using "Books".

What i Have tried.

```
 select book.author.shop.name from Book book where book.id = 1
```

I just need shop name and i have book details. How to fetch only shop name without loading authors and books object?

Comment: Did the query you tried not work? What was wrong with it? Also, any reason you need to use such an old hibernate version?

Comment: It works, But it fetches complete book object, author object and Shop object. I am looking for performance optimization as i just need only shop name

Comment: I think you should go with a native SQL query in that case. I don't believe that HQL can do it.